# Java NIO: connection forcibly closed

Tags: java, sockets, exception, nio

I was trying to implement a simple HTTP client using java NIO. But I get an error that the connection was forcibly closed by the remote host before the all data was read.
Using ordinary sockets, everything works fine.

Here's an example:

```
private static final String REQUEST = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n";

void channel() {
    try {
        SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("stackoverflow.com", 80));
        while (!sc.isConnected()) {
        }

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16*1024);
        buf.put(REQUEST.getBytes());
        buf.rewind();
        sc.write(buf);

        buf.rewind();
        while (sc.read(buf) > 0) {
            buf.rewind();
            System.out.println(new String(buf.array()));
            buf.clear();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void socket() {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("stackoverflow.com", 80);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        out.write(REQUEST);
        out.flush();

        String l;
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Works:
    new Test().socket();
    // Exception:
    new Test().channel();
}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at at.maph.tlsproxy.client.Test.channel(Test.java:39)
at at.maph.tlsproxy.client.Test.main(Test.java:70)
```

Has it something to do that I'm using a buffered reader with the socket, but not with the channel? If so, how can I make a channel buffer the read data?

Comment: You are ignoring the result of the write(). What did it return?  Also your 'while (!sc.isConnected())' loop is pointless. It can never execute with this blocking mode code: the socket is either connected after the open() call or an exception is thrown.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out now after checking write()'s return value, which was 16.384, so random data was sent to the server. The problem was with calling `rewind` on the buffer, instead, `flip` has to be used!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out now after checking `write()`'s return value, which was 16.384, so random data was sent to the server. The problem was with calling [`rewind`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind%28%29) on the buffer, instead, [`flip`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip%28%29) has to be used:

```
void channel() {
    try {
        SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("stackoverflow.com", 80));

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16*1024);
        buf.put(REQUEST.getBytes());
        buf.flip();     // <--------- Here
        sc.write(buf);

        buf.rewind();
        while (sc.read(buf) > 0) {
            buf.flip();   // <------- And here
            System.out.println(new String(buf.array()));
            buf.clear();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```